# Hibernate keep coonection after explisit destroying service registry

Tags: java, hibernate, database-connection, connection-pooling

My goal is to generate DDL during build time. I have `exec-maven-plugin` with `goal` to execute `main` method below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = null;
        try {
            Persistence.generateSchema(PERSISTENCE_UNIT, null);
        } finally {
            sessionFactory = emf.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
            sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().destroy();
        }
}
```

my `persistence.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ddl-gen">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>***</class>
        <class>***</class>
        <class>***</class>

        <properties>


            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target"
                      value="${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/sql/init.sql"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://***/~/***"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>



        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

But the problem is Hibernate wont kill DB connection even if I do it explicitly. Execution does not finishing and the process is endless

Logs:

```
16:11:41.062 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry - Not binding SessionFactory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
16:11:41.062 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator - wasInitiallyAutoCommit=false
16:11:41.062 [main] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
16:11:41.066 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl - Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
16:11:41.066 [main] INFO org.hibernate.orm.connections - HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:h2:tcp://***/~/***]
16:11:41.067 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl - Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
16:12:10.932 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl - Connection pool now considered primed; min-size will be maintained
```

Intresting thing is that I have `[pool-2-thread-1]` It means Hibernate creates new pool. because without explisit killing i have this log:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Persistence.generateSchema(PERSISTENCE_UNIT, null);
}

16:07:26.890 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry - Not binding SessionFactory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
16:07:26.895 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator - wasInitiallyAutoCommit=false
16:07:26.896 [main] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
16:07:54.274 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl - Connection pool now considered primed; min-size will be maintained
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution.

The problem with Hibernate is that he can't close connection. (this was not fixed in my solution).

So the idea was not create this connection per generation. 
Hibernate provides dummy `ConnectionProvider.class`

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl
```

which is not good for this purpose because it throws `RuntimeException`

see below:

```
@Override
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "The application must supply JDBC connections" );
}
```

So my idea was create my custom implementation of `ConnectionProvider.class`and using `persistence.xml` and `<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="com.akhambir.ddl.ddl_gen.DLLGeneratorConnectionProvider"/>` use it within my persistence-unit.

`DLLGeneratorConnectionProvider.class` has no implementation inside, just returns not implemented anonymous `Connection` and `Statement` from `getConnection()` which helps avoid creation real connection for `HibernatePersistenceProvider.class`.

Also find my workable version of the schema-generation at build time on GitHub : https://github.com/akhambir/jpa2.1-schema-generator-with-hibernate